# Parsing numbers in Python

Tags: python, parsing

i want to take inputs like this 
10 12

13 14

15 16

..

how to take this input , as two diffrent integers so that i can multiply them in python 
after every 10 and 12 there is newline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem very well, it seems you want to parse two int separated from a space.

In python you do:

```
s = raw_input('Insert 2 integers separated by a space: ')
a,b = [int(i) for i in s.split(' ')]
print a*b
```

Explanation:

```
s = raw_input('Insert 2 integers separated by a space: ')
```

raw_input takes everything you type (until you press enter) and returns it as a string, so:

```
>>> raw_input('Insert 2 integers separated by a space: ')
Insert 2 integers separated by a space: 10 12
'10 12'
```

In s you have now '10 12', the two int are separated by a space, we split the string at the space with

```
>>> s.split(' ')
['10', '12']
```

now you have a list of strings, you want to convert them in int, so:

```
>>> [int(i) for i in s.split(' ')]
[10, 12]
```

then you assign each member of the list to a variable (a and b) and then you do the product a*b

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('inputfile.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    # the next line is equivalent to:
    # s1, s2 = line.split(' ')
    # a = int(s1)
    # b = int(s2)
    a, b = map(int, line.split(' '))
    print a*b
```

Comment: You cannot make any assumptions about where the newlines are. You might have to add all numbers to a large list (or write a similar generator) and from there pair them off.

Comment: @Tom: thanks, but I did not quite get you. Would you mind explaining that again?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions (`re`-module)

```
import re

test = "10 11\n12 13" # Get this input from the files or the console

matches = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s*(\d+)", test)
products = [ int(a) * int(b)  for a, b in matches ]

# Process data
print(products)
```

Comment: Overkill - Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Comment: Some people when confronted to a problem think, "I know, I'll quote Jamie Zawinski." Now they've got two problems.

http://simonwillison.net/2009/Feb/25/twoproblems/

Comment: Some people, when facing a problem, think "I'll use regular expressions." Now they have HORDES OF CUTE PEOPLE WANTING TO SLEEP WITH THEM http://twitter.com/yoz/status/1060969730

Comment: EVERYBODY STAND BACK. I know regular expressions.