# Python - Need to cut user input and run the numbers in a loop

Tags: python-2.7

I'm not that great at python just getting snippets from here and there.

Right now I have user input, button click that runs the user's input and that is working for individual single inputs.

I am trying to make a user input with multiple answers
Example "1, 2, 5, 7, 23" -> To infinity amount

When submitted I need those answers to run in a loop until they are all used up.

So 5 answers would run the loop 5 times, each time using a different number from the user input.

By "each time using a different number" I mean I will be running a modbus coil command and those integers will be the coil address. Thus turning on or off those coils via the running loop.

So something like..

```
usernumbers = self.txtinput.get_text()
usernumbers.split()
usernumbersamount = len(usernumbers.split()
while usernumbers <= useramount:
    modbus command goes here
```

Thats about as far as I can get of it will even work, Maybe it needs to be in an array for it to work?

sorry if user input looks funny this will be ran in a browser

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two values from one input in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961263/two-values-from-one-input-in-python)

Comment: That doesn't help. - Can't write infinity amount of variables

Comment: Oh give me a break. It shows you how to do two separated by space and you can't generalize that to more than two? Come on, dude.

Answer (score 0):

If the user separates the numbers using always the same character (space for instance) you can write:

```
usernumbers = self.txtinput.get_text()
for coil_address in [usernumbers.split()]:
    self.run_coil_command(coil_address)
```

Change the `split()` by providing the separator used in you application: `split(',')`, `split(':')`, ...

Comment: The ending value needs to be an int, not a list. The integer will be converted into hex through the modbus library. And the command has to be sent one at a time. Its why i was asking how the list can be broken down into an infinite number because the value could be well over 100. Who would type in 100 numbers --- I don't know.

Comment: @Chris I don't understand your need. Can you be more precise on the scenario with example for each step (user input(s), desired value(s), ...) ?