# How to input several float variables at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input

For example: (I know this is wrong, I just need to figure out the correct way.)

```
x, y, z = float(input('Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be.'))
```

So they would type `1 2 3` and each variable would be assigned in the corresponding order.

Comment: Please add a language tag

Comment: The question is not clear. At least add the language tag.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7388131/4824627) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/961300/4824627), they are very similar

Comment: FYI: You'll get more attention for your question if you use the general [tag:python] tag.

Comment: Thank you all, first time using this site, my apologies!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` returns a single string, so you need to split it up:

```
>>> input('Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: ').split()
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 1.23 4.56 7.89
['1.23', '4.56', '7.89']
```

... and then convert each resulting string to a `float`:

```
>>> [float(s) for s in input('Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: ').split()]
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 9.87 6.54 3.21
[9.87, 6.54, 3.21]
```

... at which point you can assign the result to `x`, `y` and `z`:

```
>>> x, y, z = [float(s) for s in input('Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: ').split()]
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 1.47 2.58 3.69
>>> x
1.47
>>> y
2.58
>>> z
3.69
```

Of course, if the user inputs the wrong number of floats, you'll have a problem:

```
>>> x, y, z = [float(s) for s in input('Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: ').split()]
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 12.34 56.78
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

... so it's probably a good idea to deal with it:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x, y, z = [float(s) for s in input('Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: ').split()]
...     except ValueError:
...         print('Please enter THREE values!')
...     else:
...         break
... 
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 1 2 3 4 5
Please enter THREE values!
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 6 7
Please enter THREE values!
Enter what you would like x, y, and z to be: 8 9 0
>>> x
8.0
>>> y
9.0
>>> z
0.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for, much appreciated. And for my project it asks for length width and height so they have to enter 3 values.