# How to ask for two inputs in Python?

Tags: python

```
# Profit and Loss
# Function to calculate Profit.

def Profit(costPrice, sellingPrice):
    profit = (sellingPrice - costPrice)

    return profit


# Function to calculate Loss.
def Loss(costPrice, sellingPrice):
    Loss = (costPrice - sellingPrice)

    return Loss

if __name__ == "__main__":

    input(costPrice, sellingPrice)

    if sellingPrice == costPrice:
        print("No profit nor Loss")

    elif sellingPrice > costPrice:
        print(Profit(costPrice,
                     sellingPrice), "Profit")

    else:
        print(Loss(costPrice,
                   sellingPrice), "Loss")
```

The error code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/sharv/PycharmProjects/FInal Robotic/Finals.py", line 18, in <module>
    input(costPrice, sellingPrice) NameError: name 'costPrice' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Between the confusion with `input` and the awkward local variables in the functions, my guess is that whatever Python tutorial you're following was written by a BASIC programmer who concluded that Python is "basically the same thing" as the language she knows. I might recommend looking for a different tutorial.

Comment: Old question, but the first answer has Python 2 and 3 solutions: [Two values from one input in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961263/two-values-from-one-input-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input(costPrice, sellingPrice)
```

Whoever told you `input` takes output variables as arguments is mistaken. If you want to input into the two variables, you'll do so as follows

```
costPrice = input()
sellingPrice = input()
```

You'll also likely want to convert them to numbers.

```
costPrice = float(input())
sellingPrice = float(input())
```

Comment: Yeah I've got it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to input 2 values from the user, you will have to do it like that:

```
cost_price = input("Enter Cost Price: ")
sell_price = input("Enter Selling Price: ")
```

The `input` function in python takes as argument a string text to display to the user (An optional argument) and returns the inputed value from the user (as a `str` object). If you would like to convert those values into numbers, you will have to do something like:

```
# integer values
cost_price = int(input("Enter Cost Price: "))
sell_price = int(input("Enter Selling Price: "))

# OR:

# Floating point values
cost_price = float(input("Enter Cost Price: "))
sell_price = float(input("Enter Selling Price: "))
```